# SQL Server 2012 Stored Procedure connecting to web service with TLS 1.2

Tags: sql-server, tls1.2, serverxmlhttp

We have a stored procedure that uses sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP' to connect to a web service. This web service has now disabled TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.2. I have confirmed that TLS 1.2 is enabled on the server, but my calls to this service continue to fail. Is there a way to force the ServerXMLHTTP object to use TLS 1.2?

The same call works flawlessly from a SQL Server 2017 instance.

Comment: ServerXMLHTTP is a Windows component, so this is not going to depend on your SQL Server version or configuration.

Comment: It seems using WinHttpRequest.5.1 and setting option 9 would do the trick, however I'm unable to find documentation on how to properly set this option...